# Delete empty numpy arrays is not working properly

Tags: python, numpy

I try to delete all arrays that are empty. Somehow it is not working. Can somebody help? What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks

```
image_input = pickle.load( open( "images.pkl", "rb" ) )
images = np.empty((500,400,400,3))

for i, image in enumerate(image_input):
    if image.shape == (400,400,3) and i < 500:
        images[i] = image
    elif image.shape != (400,400,3) and i < 500:
        np.delete(images, images[i], axis=0)
        print('else')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `image_input` seems to be a list, and you want to change the size of that list, it is probably best to use simple list comprehensions, and generate the image array afterwards:

```
image_input = pickle.load(open("images.pkl", "rb" ))

# Keep only images with right size
image_input = [image for image in image_input if image.shape == (400,400,3)]

# Create image tensor
images = np.array(image_input)

# Limit to first 500 images only
images = images[:500, ...]
```

Comment: this is way cleaner! Thank you. I think you meant images = images[:500, ...]

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because np.delete does not work `inplace`. It returns a copy with the values deleted. See from the offical [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html).

So replacing

```
np.delete(images, images[i], axis=0)
```

with

```
images = np.delete(images, images[i], axis=0)
```

should work.

You can just use the native Python `del` like that:

```
In[50]: images = np.empty((500,400,400,3))

In[51]: del images

In[52]: images
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-53-49a4f536d6a7>", line 1, in <module>
    images

NameError: name 'images' is not defined
```

Comment: sorry I don't want to delete the whole array only the arrays on axis=0 that are empty.

Comment: Sorry I got that wrong! See the edit. You have to reassign the images object for it to work. I guess.

Comment: This solution does not make that much sense: the image is not in `images` yet, and the second argument to `np.delete()` should be the index, not the data.

Answer (score -1):

I had to reasign images. Thanks Nethale!

image_input = pickle.load( open( "images.pkl", "rb" ) )
images = np.zeros((800,400,400,3))

```
image_input = pickle.load( open( "images.pkl", "rb" ) )
images = np.zeros((800,400,400,3))

for i, image in enumerate(image_input):
    if image.shape == (400,400,3):
        images[i] = image


for i, image in enumerate(images):
    if (not np.any(image)):
        images = np.delete(images, image, axis=0)
        print('deleted')
```

Comment: Incorrect usage of `np.delete()` very likely makes this an incorrect solution.